# How can I customize the bottom navigation items?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want To make this bottom navigation

[image]

So how can I do it, the centered one is always like the image if selected or not, and the other will be selected as shown in the image.

Comment: Anchor FAB to bottomNavigationBar

Comment: @Sourav Bagchi OK I will try it, Thanks :)

Comment: See this https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html

Comment: it doesn't give me the ability to arrange them like the design